# CSS Media queries not working on HubSpot site

Tags: css, media-queries, hubspot

I'm attempting to write media queries for a site built using HubSpot CRM and my queries are not doing anything. I've added the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` in my head and the following css:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1045px) {
   .hs-menu-wrapper.hs-menu-flow-horizontal>ul li a {
     font-size: 0.9em;
   }  
}
```

this is supposed to change the font-size of the navigation links so they don't break to a new line - http://www.steelbridgeins.com/

please help! -_-

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `all` for the device attribute as it is the default and I think you mean to use `max-width` instead if you are trying to target all screen-widths below 1045px.

```
@media (max-width: 1045px) {
   .hs-menu-wrapper.hs-menu-flow-horizontal>ul li a {
     font-size: 0.9em;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is occurring due to the nesting of media queries. Currently, in style.min.css, you are using:

```
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* some stylings */
    @media (max-width: 1045px) {
       .hs-menu-wrapper.hs-menu-flow-horizontal>ul li a {
           font-size: 0.9em;
       }
    }  
}
```

If you move the media query you desire outside of the other media query, as shown below, this should resolve your issue.

```
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* some stylings */
}

@media (max-width: 1045px) {
   .hs-menu-wrapper.hs-menu-flow-horizontal>ul li a {
       font-size: 0.9em;
   }
}
```